# Ficheros: funciones vs. llamadas al sistema

Tags: c

Tengo dos preguntas relacionadas con el I/O de ficheros:

1. ¿Qué es más rápido para acceder a un fichero (si es que alguna es mejor), las funciones de C (`fopen`, `fprintf`, `fseek`, etc.) o las llamadas a UNIX (`open`, `write`, `lseek`, etc.)?
2. ¿Cómo se puede leer texto formateado usando llamadas al sistema (igual que se hace con `fscanf`, por ejemplo para leer números enteros)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> 1) ¿qué es más rápido para acceder a un fichero (si es que alguna es mejor), las funciones de C (fopen, fprintf, fseek, etc) o las llamadas a UNIX (open, write, lseek, etc)?

`open` abre un fichero y te proporciona acceso directo al mismo. Las funciones de la API de unix acceden al fichero a través del descriptor proporcionado por `open`.

`fopen` abre un fichero, le asigna un buffer y te ofrece acceso a dicho buffer. Los cambios no se plasman instantáneamente sino que se almacenan en el buffer intermedio hasta que se vuelcan definitivamente al fichero. El resto de funciones `f*` trabajan sobre el mencionado buffer. Sobra decir que para abrir el fichero, `fopen` tiene que acabar llamando a la API de *linux* (recordemos que *unix* fue el germen, actualmente prácticamente todo es *linux*).

Así a bote pronto se podría decir que `open` debería proporcionar mejores tiempos de respuesta (al fin y al cabo `fopen` implica una llamada a `open`), peeeero ese buffer secundario puede llegar a hacer maravillas así que la conclusión a la que puedes llegar es que dependiendo de lo que estés haciendo existirá un mecanismo mejor que otro.

Por otro lado, la familia `f*` son de más alto nivel que las funciones de la API de Linux, lo que te permitirá simplificar muchísimas operaciones relacioandas con el tratamiento de ficheros.

No es una respuesta concluyente pero es que ninguna lo va a ser.

> 2) ¿Cómo se puede leer texto formateado usando llamadas al sistema (igual que se hace con fscanf, por ejemplo para leer números enteros)?

Como te he dicho, la API de linux es de bajo nivel y no implementa muchas utilidades existentes en funciones de alto nivel... te toca currarte los mecanismos de conversión.

Comment: O leer cadenas con `read()` y usar `sscanf()` para parsearlas, que a fin de cuentas es lo que hace `fscanf()`. El principal problema es que `read()` no está orientado a líneas.